# C++ finding power and absolute value of numbers

Tags: c++, math

I have numbers of the following form:

```
1). 3.1456e10
2). 56.7
3). 1.62166e+15
4). 1.9651e+87
5). 335544.32e+10
```

Now, I want to multiply these numbers by 10 till number after e(i.e. 10^) is atmost 255 and atleast 0. Also the number before "e" is atmost 2^24.
E.g. for the above numbers I want to express as:

```
1). 3.1456e10= 31456e6 (before_e: 31456, after_e: 6)
2). 56.7 = 56.7 (before_e: 56, after_e: 0)
3). 1.62166e+15 = 162166e+10 (before_e:162166, after_e: 10)
4). 1.9651e+87= 19651e+83 (before_e:19651, after_e:83)
5). 335544.32e+10=3355443 (before_e:3355443, after_e:9)
```

I know I can keep multiplying numbers till they are less than 2^24. But how do I find out the number after "e" in C++. Therefore, I am not able to understand as to how can I find the value of before_e and after_e using C++ program.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `1.23E4` is *the same number* as `12.3E3`. You're not "multiplying" the number. You're just representing it differently.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a string like `3.1456e10` into two numbers, or how to find the output as explained by your requirements?

Comment: Please do some research and study some maths. Once you know the proper names for "the number before e" etc., you should have no trouble finding out how to determine those numbers in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes I want to represent the numbers differently. I want to get before_e=12 and after_e=3 in ur example

Comment: @interjay Yes. Apart from 3.1456e10 my numbers could also be 56.7

Comment: I also don't see how your example relates to your requirements. `3.1456e10` is already in a form where the exponent is "atmost 255 and atleast 0", and the "number before "e" is atmost 2^24". Why does it need changing?

Comment: Why do you change `3.1456e10` to `31456e6` and not to `3145600e4`?

Comment: @KerrekSB actually i need to store the value before exponent and after exponent separately -- also I need to keep multipling the number e.g. 3.1456e10 till it is lesser than 2^24.

Comment: @Kolmar because I want to keep multiplying by 10 till the decimal part is not 0 which reaches when I have 31456e6 so I do not go further

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple algorithm for obtaining the desired representation of a positive number `x`:

1. If `x > 1e255`, compute `y = x / 1e255` and print `y * 1e255` (with `y` printed in fixed-point notation).
2. Otherwise, if `x < 1` print `x * 1e0` (with `x` printed in fixed-point notation).
3. Otherwise print `x` in its standard decimal scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do exactly what you need :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double a = 335544.32e+10; //arbitrary testing number
cout << a << endl; 
int after_e = 0;
//now checks if the number is divisible by ten, and the length of the exponent
while((long)a%10==0&&after_e<256){
   a = a/10; //removes a multiplication by 10
   after_e++;//increments the exponent variable
}
long before_e = (long)a;
//follows the constraint of before_e being less than 2^24, and truncates the rest of the number
while(before_e>16777216){
   before_e /= 10;
   after_e++;
}
cout<<"before_e "<<before_e<<" , "<<"after_e "<<after_e<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code is non-trivial, it could be a good idea to explain it a little.